# Как через onCliсk передать в функцию сразу 2 значения с уникальными id. Игра "Угадай-ка для 2 игроков". JavaScript

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

**Проблема**:

1. Не могу реализовать при нажатии на клавишу "Угадать" обработку значений, введенных игроками в поля ввода .

1.2. JS-скрипт обрабатывает только первое поле ввода, единственный раз выдает ответ и далее скрипт замирает.

**Что я хочу сделать** (новичок, не знаю - как дальше):

1. Нажатие на клавишу "Угадать" должно передать сразу два ответа в функцию на обработку.
2. JS-скрпит должен обработать эти два ответа
3. По каждому игроку ожидается ответ (возможно через .innerHTML) о результате попытки игрока (типа "не верно", "Игрок № ... угадал")
4. Общее кол-во попыток угадать   = 4

**Суть**:
Игра на 2 персоны, надо одному из игроков угадать загаданную компьютером рандомную цифру.

**Внешнее оформление**:
Html+CSS.
2 поля ввода (input) для каждого игрока и одна кнопка "Угадать" (onClick = "...")

[image: Скрин "УгадайКи"]

```js
var vopros = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
var igrok1 = '№1';
var igrok2 = '№2';
let otvet1, otvet2;

//забираю ответ из полей ввода


//вызов ф-ции от нажатия клавиши "Угадать"

function game(otvet, gamer) {

  for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    function zaborOtveta(otvet) {
      if (igrok1) {
        otvet1 = +document.getElementById("otvet1").value;
        return otvet1;
      } else if (igrok2) {
        otvet2 = +document.getElementById("otvet2").value;
        return otvet2;
      }
    }

    //otvet = prompt("Выход клавиша q. Угадай число от 0 до 10. Ход игрока : " + gamer);
    otvet = zaborOtveta(otvet);

    if (otvet == "q" || otvet == 'esc' || otvet == null) {
      return false;
    }
    otvet = +otvet;

    if (otvet == vopros) {
      alert("Число угадал игрок " + gamer);
      return false;
    } else if (otvet > vopros) {
      alert("Чет-то много");
    } else if (otvet < vopros) {
      alert("Слишком мало");
    }
  } //for():end

  return true;
} //function (): end


let n = 0;
while (n < 4) {
  //искусственно ограничил кол-во попыток, чтоб не было бесконечного цикла

  n++
  if (!game(otvet1, igrok1))
    break;

  n++
  if (!game(otvet2, igrok2))
    break;

} //while ( ): end

alert("Было загадано:" + vopros);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #DA3725;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  min-width: 1300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b7ba;
  background-color: #F8F000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.header .selected {
  color: #000;
}

.center {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header a {
  color: #F90505;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.header span {
  padding: 0 38px;
}

.content {
  min-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
}

.content h1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2e353d;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 63px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.content h3 {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 41px;
  margin-bottom: 52px;
}

.content h5 {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content img {
  margin-left: 17px;
  width: 389px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.content .box_text {
  width: 671px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  padding: 49px 48px 51px 76px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.content .box_text p {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
}

.content .box_text a {
  color: #40678a;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.content .media {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.content .box {
  background-color: #A4A9A0;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
  padding-top: 37px;
  padding-left: 38px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.content .box p {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 37px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content .box input {
  border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 457px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.content .box a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #8cbbd3;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 11px 51px;
}

.content .box a:hover {
  background-color: #5ba1d3;
}

.footer {
  /* # == id */
  background-color: #434445;
  min-width: 1300px;
  /*float: left;*/
  height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a4a4a4;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 140px;
}

.footer a {
  color: inherit;
}

#a,
#b {
  font-weight: 400;
}

#otvet1,
#otvet2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


/*для Угадай-ка 2*/

.box_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 500px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 85px;
  align-content: center;
}

.box_grid #otvet1,
.box_grid #otvet2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.box_grid #a,
.box_grid #b {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.box_grid .btn {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
    <a href="puzzle.html">Загадки</a>
    <a href="guess.html">Угадайка</a>
    <a href="minmax_HidenText_v1.html">MinMax</a>
    <a href="Ugadka2gamer_v1.html">УгадайКа-2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contentWrap">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="center">

        <h1>Игра "Угадай-ка (2 игрока)"</h1>

        <div class="box box_grid">

          <p id="a">Игрок №1 вводит число :</p>
          <input type="text" id="otvet1">

          <p id="b">Игрок №2 вводит число :</p>
          <input type="text" id="otvet2">

          <br>
          <a href="#" onClick="game();" class="btn">Угадать</a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Copyright &copy; #SamboRulit
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не стал заморачиваться с дизайном, думаю так понятно будет, как игру сделать.

```js
const rand = (min, max) => Math.round(min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1))

const $form = document.forms[0];

let num;
const reset = () => {
  num = rand(1, 10);
  $form.round.value = 4;
  $form.p1.value = $form.p1.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = ``;
  $form.p2.value = $form.p2.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = ``;
  console.log(num);
}
reset();

const check = ($i, msg) => {
  const val = +$i.value;
  if (num === val) {
    alert(msg);
    return true;
  }
  $i.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = val < num ? `Маловато будет` : `Многовато будет`;
  return false;
}


$form.addEventListener(`submit`, e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const p1 = +$form.p1.value;
  const p2 = +$form.p2.value;

  if (p1 === num && p1 === p2) {
    alert(`Оба игрока выиграли`);
    return reset();
  }

  if (check($form.p1, `Игрок 1 выиграл`)) return reset();
  if (check($form.p2, `Игрок 2 выиграл`)) return reset();

  $form.round.value = +$form.round.value - 1;
  if (+$form.round.value > 0) return;
  alert(`Все проиграли`);
  reset();
});

$form.addEventListener(`reset`, reset);
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Попыток<input type="number" name="round" value="4" autocomplete="off" readonly></label>
  <label>Игрок 1<input type="number" name="p1" autocomplete="off"><i></i></label>
  <label>Игрок 2<input type="number" name="p2" autocomplete="off"><i></i></label>
  <button type="submit">Угадать</button>
  <button type="reset">Сбросить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не используйте round в генерации рандомного числа.

Comment: Что не так с Math.round?

Comment: @nazarpunk, благодарю за ответ. 
Для меня это решение сложное, т.е. выдает ошибку, а я даже не знаю как ее исправить. До такого уровня понимания JS как до Луны ползком (походу я только-только преодолел путь длинной в 10 см, и мне до цели всего-то каких-то 384 тыс.км).

Ошибка в отладчике на точке:
$form.round.value = 4;

К сожалению, я не понимаю пока таких решений и поэтому не могу сделать правку кода.

Но все равно благодарю, что отозвались.

Comment: `$form.round` это обращение к `<input name="round">`. Если у вас его нет, то соответственно будет ошибка.